# Return SQLite Value in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to return the value of sqlite insert. In my code when the insert operation fail return -1 (API sqlite said: "the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred"). The problem is that always the insert fail and I receive other value in my code.

```
//Function in my class DAtabase
    public int insert(HashMap<String, String> queryValues,String table) {
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            long result = 0;
            switch (table) {

            case "Log":
                values.put("relacion", queryValues.get("relacion"));
                values.put("objetoPadre", queryValues.get("objetoPadre"));
                values.put("objeto", queryValues.get("objeto"));
                values.put("interaccion", queryValues.get("interaccion"));
                values.put("tiempo", queryValues.get("tiempo"));
                values.put("sincro", queryValues.get("sincro"));
                result=database.insert("Log", null, values);    
                database.close();
                System.out.println("Value:"result);
                return (int) result;//result here is -1
            case "Conf_spinner":
                values.put("relacion",queryValues.get("relacion"));
                values.put("interaccion",queryValues.get("interaccion"));
    result=database.insert("Conf_spinner", null, values);
                database.close();
                System.out.println("Value:"result);//result here is -1
                return (int) result;

            default:
                database.close();
                return 1;
                break;
            }
        }
```

This part of the code return -1 if the insert fail or other value in other case.

Here is my code:

```
//Code of my android activiy
    int value = myDatabase.insert(queryValues, "Conf_spinner");

    if(value==-1) //value always set other number that isn't -1.
       showMessaging();
    else
    Log.e("MyTag","FAIL INSERCION");
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you know the insertion fails? Also note that you're not saving the value returned by the insert on `case "Conf_spinner"`.

Comment: if the code return -1 the insercion fail, why do you have  if(value == -1) {// error } ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal insert method doesn't tell you what the exception that occurred so i suggest you set flag as debug mode

```
private final static boolean debug_mode = true;
```

and when you insert in your case :

```
if(debug_mode){

    // this method will throw clear exception so you can handle 
    result=database.insertOrThrow("Log", null, values); 
  } else{

     result=database.insert("Log", null, values);
  }
```

and when you handle the exception you have choose to return the debug_mode to false

Comment: I have had this thay you suggest me. I Changed in my code database.insert for database.inserOrThorw and the procces returned FATAL EXEPCION.....

Comment: could you edit your answer with the logcat exception ??

Comment: I had forgotten to put a return value in one case. insertOrThrow works perfectly. Thank you very much for the help.